# "TypeError: hashConstructor is not a constructor", error when using "@aws-sdk/signature-v4" on AWS-Lambda

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sha256

I am developing a lambda in TypeScript that uses the `"@aws-sdk/signature-v4"`  package and when I attempt to run the deployed lambda in the lambda console I receive the following error:

```
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "hashConstructor is not a constructor",
  "trace": [
    "TypeError: hashConstructor is not a constructor",
    "    at getPayloadHash (/var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/dist-cjs/getPayloadHash.js:17:26)",
    "    at SignatureV4.signRequest (/var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/dist-cjs/SignatureV4.js:93:71)"
  ]
}
```

So far I have looked into the known issues for this package and I came across this https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/3590 on Github. I am also using the `"@aws-crypto/sha256-js"` package which is supposed to offer a workaround, but so far doesn't seem to have had any effect on this error.     `"esModuleInterop": true` is set in my `tsconfig.json` since `"@aws-crypto/sha256-js"` is a commonJS module.
Any help would be appreciated!

How the packages are being imported:

```
import * as crypto from "@aws-crypto/sha256-js";
const { Sha256 } = crypto;
```

UPDATE

I have logged out the following `SignatureV4` object

```
const signer = new SignatureV4({
    credentials: defaultProvider(),
    region: AWS_REGION,
    service: "appsync",
    sha256: Sha256,
  });
```

and I am seeing that Sha256 is coming through as being undefined. I am trying to see why this is the case.

SOLVED

I had to change the way I was importing the packages, pretty dumb mistake and I hope by posting this others will avoid doing what I did.

The way that worked

```
import crypto from "@aws-crypto/sha256-js";
const { Sha256 } = crypto;
```

The way that didn't work is at the beginning of this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the packages like this

```
import crypto from "@aws-crypto/sha256-js";
const { Sha256 } = crypto;
```

And not like this

```
import * as crypto from "@aws-crypto/sha256-js";
const { Sha256 } = crypto;
```

Comment: Note, that importing it the first way in this answer will cause tests in Jest to break and you will need to go back to importing the second way in your handler for testing purposes.